# Где почитать про хорошие практики организации бизнес-логики в Laravel (Lumen)?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Начав изучать Laravel и Lumen я пришел к выводу, что написать какой-никакой сайт получится быстро. Но меня всё не покидает ощущения что я пишу го***код. В документации расписано именно КАК работаю те, или иные механики. Но не показано как их грамотно комбинировать и взаимодействовать с ними.

Где можно брать пример такого?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, но конкретно к фреймворку он имеет слабое отношение. Есть сборник хороших практик https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices или гуглится. 
Тэйлор (creator of laravel) сделал акцент на элегантность кода и это зашло сообществу. Ведь работать с элегантным и структурированным кодом куда приятней, чем с го***кодом))
Но мое мнение (личное), что элегантность кода (стурктура, следование правилам форматирования и именования, оптимальная работа и т.д.(SOLID,DRY,etc)) должна быть в любом коде, который ты пишешь, будь то `php`, `java`,`js`, etc...

Comment: `пример такого` на гитхабе ищите.